# Passing a video stream from Python to VB.NET through UDP

Tags: python, vb.net, opencv, sockets, emgucv

I need to pass a live video stream from a Python analytics backend to a VB.NET WPF frontend. I'm using a Python server and a VB.NET client communicating via UDP.

This is what I have so far on both ends:

Python Server:

```
import cv2
from socket import *
import socket
import numpy as np
import sys


_s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
_address = ('localhost',5000)
_quality=[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),80]

vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov")
while(1):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    image = frame

    # processing

    result, imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image, _quality)
    data = np.array(imgencode)

    stringData = data.tobytes()
    _s.sendto(stringData,_address)
```

VB.NET client (Using a console app for testing):

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Module Program
    Dim Mat = New Emgu.CV.Mat(New System.Drawing.Size(640, 480), Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 3)
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Using socket As UdpClient = New UdpClient(5000)

            Try

                While True
                    Dim remoteEP = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000)
                    Dim data As Byte() = socket.Receive(remoteEP)
                    Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.Imdecode(data, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.ReducedColor8, Mat)
                    Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.Imshow("", Mat)
                End While

            Catch __unusedSocketException1__ As SocketException
                Throw
            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module
```

The code I've got so far doesn't throw any errors, but the output isn't displayed in EmguCV ImShow() window. Any help or alternative solutions for my use case are appreciated!

Comment: where's the WaitKey? Imshow expects WaitKey or else it won't work. or you can NOT use imshow, but instead show the data in the GUI itself.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That was it! A newbie mistake on my part... Thanks for pointing it out! Yes the data is to be displayed in the GUI itself at the end of it. I was using Imshow() for testing. Thanks for your help again!